# Create a continuous bootstrap grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create something like as shown in the following image using bootstrap. But when I use .rows and .col-sm bootstrap grids, it starts from the very next line leaving gaps between vertical columns. I want to make it exact like as shown in pic. I searched all through but I'm only getting bootstrap grid examples which doesn't do continuous grid of block. 
[Expected Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZMiN.jpg)

Comment: you could try CSS grid layouts as an alternative. plenty of tutorials online

Answer (score 0):

*CCS Grid* is actually the easiest and most modern way to do this.
Follow this link to see what you can do with it:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

But be **careful** because not each browser has implemented its entire functionality yet (https://caniuse.com/#search=grid).